# Why does maps.yandex.com load sooo slowly?

Tags: performance, website

Considering that maps.yandex.com is the Russian equivalent of Google Maps (and hence, presumably, very popular), why does the website perform so extremely poorly? I'm viewing the website from the UK via a decent, consistent internet connection (80MB/20MB), yet it performs extremely slowly on Chrome, Firefox and IE11. I have no problems viewing any other site.

I can't imagine it would perform that slowly in Russia and was wondering whether there was some regional issue that was to blame?

Comment: As Yandex is mostly directed to Russia there is no so much sense to have big bandwidth to the world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it works fine for me here in Germany, I’d say your internet connection (or, more precisely: Your route to Yandex) is to blame, yes.

Comment: retry with non ISP  DNS  ie  something like google /OpenDNS heck even MS / Apple/ or  Amazon DNS  ---had  less than 8 secs to a full gpu draw on my connection (comcast --us East coast )  resolve was merely 1.5 secs  using Google / OpenDNS / Local university as Primary DNS (as secondary I have apple and a few less local --geographically   universities

Comment: Ah, yes. That might also be a factor. I’m using Google DNS for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: DNS is not important (very much) in this case. After initial request the resolv is cached and used for next requests

Comment: Daniel I use google and OpenDns for both too

Comment: There is indeed a routing problem, I'll mention it to the ISP.